# Disable Message History in processmaker

Tags: process, workflow, message, history

is there any way to disable "Message History" in processmaker, or perhaps disable the possibility of resending message for some of the users? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A latest version of ProcessMaker includes the possibility to disable it based on permissions. Check this more info:

Message History Permission
Available version: 2.5.1
Through ProcessMaker versions, users who had participation in a case had the option to see not only a preview of messages sent, even the privates ones, but also to resend messages to any user allowing them to know possible confidential information of a Company. Now resending emails functionality has been restricted per user.
By default, users don't have the permission to resend messages, if you want to add a permission for users to resend them open Process Permission and on Type select Message History

http://wiki.processmaker.com/index.php/2.0/Process_Permissions#Message_History_Permission

Comment: Instead of just posting the link. Please copy in the relevant content from that here as well as links may go away in future